# (Company) Doc Buffer ignoring scroll-other-window

Tags: company-mode, doc-strings

I'm trying to write my own backend for a certain tool language that has no repl. Hence, I thought it would be the best idea to parse the documentation and store it as a hash table (I'm open to other suggestions, I'm fairly new to Emacs). In general this works fine, the problems arise when the documentation is longer than a display. In this case, I would like to use scroll-other-window like anywhere else to scroll the documentation down, but it immediately jumps back to the top.

This is the basic structure of my backend:

```lisp
(defconst my--constants
  (list "asdf"
        "bsdf"
        "csdf"))

(defconst my--doc-buffer
  #s(hash-table
     size 3
     test equal
     data("asdf" "Test."
          "bsdf" "Doing\nfine."
          "csdf" "T\nh\ni\ns\n \ni\ns\n \nw\nh\ne\nr\ne\n \ni\nt\n \ng\ne\nt\ns\n \nr\ne\na\nl\nl\ny\n \nm\ne\ns\ns\ny\n.\n \nE\nv\ne\nn\n \nw\ni\nt\nh\n \ns\nc\nr\no\nl\nl\n-\no\nt\nh\ne\nr\n-\nw\ni\nn\nd\no\nw\n \ni\nt\n \nj\nu\nm\np\ns\n \nb\na\nc\nk\n.")))

(define-derived-mode my-mode prog-mode "My")

(defun my-completion-at-point ()
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
    (when bounds
      (list (car bounds)
            (cdr bounds)
            my--constants
            :exclusive 'no
            :sorted (lambda (cand) t)
            :company-doc-buffer
            (lambda (cand)
              (company-doc-buffer (gethash cand my--doc-buffer)))))))

(add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'my-completion-at-point)
```

When `company-show-doc-buffer` is called upon `csdf`, `scroll-other-window` won't do it's job properly. Instead it immediately jumps back to the head.

Are those `\n` linebreaks the wrong approach? Am I missing something else? Unfortunately I couldn't find any other backends that use doc-buffers in an offline table. Is it actually the way to go, to use a company-doc-buffer, or is there a more generic thing available/recommended?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you're calling `scroll-other-window`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing, it made me rethink my company configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the culprit: `company-quickhelp-mode` was enabled in my setup which evidently triggered the doc-buffer all the time to reload. After disabling, everything works as expected. I'll try to solve this issue also with `company-quickhelp` and add my results here later.